# How to expose endpoint on AWS EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, webclient

I'm running an EC2 Windows server on AWS. There, I have my C# backend application running endpoint `http://0.0.0.0:5000/do-something` that I would like to expose to the public.

From within the instance, I can reach the endpoint (via `http://127.0.0.1:5000/do-something`), however, not from the outside. I tried to change the inbound rules for the security group of my instance (launch-wizard-1). [image]

Then, I tried to access it from the outside by inserting it into the browser as follows: `http://public-ip-of-my-instance:5000/do-something`. Unfortunately, I could not reach the endpoint. What could be the problem?

Comment: Make sure you are accessing the machine with the correct public ip, Look out for if by any chance firewall is open for port 5000 and lastly look for if app is bound to correct ip/interface.

Comment: Windows has build in firewall.

Comment: Yes, I needed to allow port 5000 in the firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A port 5000 must be allowed in the Windows firewall to make it work.

Go to `Windows Security -> Firewall & Protection -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound Rules -> New Rule`. There, allow TCP port 5000 and leave all other settings default.